# Reading from 2 sockets in 2 threads causes data loss

Tags: c++, sockets

I have a multi-threaded Windows C++ app written in Visual Studio 6.

Within the app 2 threads are running each trying to read UDP packets on different ports.  If I protect the reading from the socket with a critical section then all the date read is fine.  Without that protection data is lost from both sockets.

Is reading from a socket not thread safe?  I've written many socket apps in the past and don't remember having to use this sort of thread protection.

Comment: Perhaps you could also add to your question some of the api calls your using to get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Within the app 2 threads are running each trying to read UDP packets on different ports.***

How much UDP data are you sending/reading?  How fast are you sending it?  How much of your data is lost?

This could be a race condition...  **Not between the two threads, but between the thread and the socket!**

I've seen problems in the past porting code from Linux to Windows.  Windows uses (used) a default UDP buffersize of 8k.  Naturally, we were sending 12k bursts, and there's just no way to read it fast enough even with a dedicated read thread!

You can change the UDP buffersize (under Windows) with something like:

```
int newBufferSize = 128 * 1024;  // 128k
setsockopt( readSocketFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *) & newBufferSize );
```

Answer (score 1):

Winsock is not guaranteed to be thread-safe.  It's up to the implementer.  Have a look [here](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/intermediate.html#threadsafety).

Answer (score 0):

Reading from one socket in two threads is not thread safe, you may not know for sure which caller gets a packet fron the underlying socket buffer first. Writing to a socket is the same. Since you're reading from two different sockets in two different threads (and I assume that each socket has its own thread), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you're not reading from the same socket? In our system we're using exactly this: 2 bound UDP sockets + 2 threads to read from them. No problems and no syncing needed..